# Python+Postman 401error

Tags: python, postman

[This is my code]

```
import requests

# after post code>
# ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LmV5SmxlSEFpT2pFMU9UUTJOalU1TmpBc0lrMXZaR1ZzSWpwN0lrTm9ZWEpoWTNSbGNuTlFaWEpFWVhraU9qVXdNREF3TENKVmMyVnlTV1FpT2pNMk16SXNJbFZ1YVhGMVpVbGtJam9pTnpObE5UVTNPR1l0WW1FMk5TMDBaVGt3TFRoallXVXRZMlEzWWpWaVlUZ3hORGhsSW4xOS5YRjFoZDltQ2hGRkpKel96UXZ5TFNJcXhTZFpucklWeXppZ1R6NWJCVHBV
URL_AUTH = 'https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1.1/authenticate'
URL_TRANSLATE = 'https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1/Minicard'
KEY = 'NzNlNTU3OGYtYmE2NS00ZTkwLThjYWUtY2Q3YjViYTgxNDhlOjc4NDM0MDRmMjNmODRlMTc5MzJlNTRiNThhMGM4MGQy'  # key before post
headers_auth = {"Authorization": "Basic" + KEY}
auth = requests.post(URL_AUTH, headers=headers_auth)
print(auth)
```

This is Postman

```
KEY - Authorization
VALUE - Basic NzNlNTU3OGYtYmE2NS00ZTkwLThjYWUtY2Q3YjViYTgxNDhlOjc4NDM0MDRmMjNmODRlMTc5MzJlNTRiNThhMGM4MGQy
```

When I write auth.text, there is no output in the console

```
import requests

# after post code>
# ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LmV5SmxlSEFpT2pFMU9UUTJOalU1TmpBc0lrMXZaR1ZzSWpwN0lrTm9ZWEpoWTNSbGNuTlFaWEpFWVhraU9qVXdNREF3TENKVmMyVnlTV1FpT2pNMk16SXNJbFZ1YVhGMVpVbGtJam9pTnpObE5UVTNPR1l0WW1FMk5TMDBaVGt3TFRoallXVXRZMlEzWWpWaVlUZ3hORGhsSW4xOS5YRjFoZDltQ2hGRkpKel96UXZ5TFNJcXhTZFpucklWeXppZ1R6NWJCVHBV
URL_AUTH = 'https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1.1/authenticate'
URL_TRANSLATE = 'https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1/Minicard'
KEY = 'NzNlNTU3OGYtYmE2NS00ZTkwLThjYWUtY2Q3YjViYTgxNDhlOjc4NDM0MDRmMjNmODRlMTc5MzJlNTRiNThhMGM4MGQy'  # key before post
headers_auth = {"Authorization": "Basic" + KEY}
auth = requests.post(URL_AUTH, headers=headers_auth)
print(auth.text)
```

Request: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSPhO.png
Postman: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2fLL.png
After running the program gives Error 401. I have triple checked all the information. Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please include code in question without image.

Comment: I found a solution.  You must have a space in "Basic " like this. Thanks, Codigo Marsa for the reply

Comment: @MaksimLevchenko you are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a space between "Basic" and the key, try

```
"Basic " + KEY
```

You should print the whole information in the response, in order to know more details about the error, hence I would add print(auth.text).

Comment: I tried and there is no output in the console with auth.text